# Is it possible to make our own quantum computer? If yes, what will it take?

Tags: architecture, experimental-realization

I am thinking as quantum computing is just a new word in tech, so let to explore it by building it or a prototype based on it so I am just wanted help in setting up and initial steps which should I keep in mind. Please tell me about each implementation step.

Comment: While the basic answer is along the lines of "with a fair bit of investment and experience, you could technically build something with a couple of qubits", the actual answer is implementation dependent and even then, there are different ways to go about doing so for each implementation, so I suggest that you narrow this down by thinking about what implementation you'd want to know about (if you've got any specific questions about specific implementations, feel free to ask), then e.g. making an [edit] to ask about a specific experimental set-up would narrow this down considerably

Comment: can you give just an overview of these step ?

Comment: Not really as things currently stand because it just depends on too much - the first thing is which implementation do you want to know about?

Comment: for all practical purposes, the answer is no (unless of course you happen to have on your hands a lot of money and people with the relevant expertise)

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 you could technically build something with a couple of qubits". what can be buid and how should i start ?

Comment: @glS I believe Heather would disagree with you there! Speaking of which, Vashi - one *relatively possible* way is to use a (photonic) nonlinear crystal. There are a few ways we could go about sorting this out - 1. I could edit your question in a couple of days to something I feel is well defined, 2. You could ping Heather in [chat] or 3. We could have a general talk in [chat] about this. Bear in mind though, that while it's technically possible, as glS mentioned, it would probably be *very* challenging and expensive if you actually wanted to give it a go, although a good learning experience

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 what are the type of implementation option We have ?